# Confused sending sms using aws [Updated: sms is delivered soo late]

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I'm writing a program that sends SMS using the AWS SNS service. I am new to this topic. So I've tried one of the codes available online.

and the code is as below.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

AWS.config.region = 'your aws region';
AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: "your access id",
    secretAccessKey: "your secret access key",
});

var sns = new AWS.SNS();
var params = {
    Message: "your message",
    MessageStructure: 'string',
    PhoneNumber: 'phone_number_without_+',
    Subject: 'your subject'
};

sns.publish(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    else console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

Here I've filled the entire data from my AWS console like `Region`, `accessKey` and `secretAccessKey`, my `mobile number`, `Subject` and `message`. post filling this when I try to run this, I get the below response.

```
{ ResponseMetadata: { RequestId: '30d54840-1aa8-5ad4-8de7-19cad1ed033f' },
  MessageId: '7cc1d99e-b835-5015-b84e-88147370a9fe' }
```

but there is no sms delivered to my mobile.

I thought that the service is not available in my country and then tried sending the message from SMS console shown below. I received a text message on my mobile.

[image]

Here I'm not using any `topic` and I need to send message individually, there is no bulk message to be sent.

Please guide me on where am I going wrong and how can I fix this.

Thanks

**Update**

Thanks for the quick test [balent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/255389/balent).

This thing is working, the saddest part is that the message is delivered after 9 hrs. I'm in India and our code starts something like this `+91XXXXXXXXXX` and I did the same. But when tried through the console(SMS screenshot), the message was instant, can someone please shower some light on how this can be fixed. i.e. the sms to be sent instantly.

Comment: Just tried this code and SMS is delivered to my phone. Maybe you misspelled phone number? Also could you try it with "+" included? Should work anyway.

Comment: Dude. Did you resolve this issue? I am also getting the same. Can you help me in this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you for your question and updated answer, to reduce time of delivery in India, setting the attribute DefaultSMSType to "Transactional" delivered it immediately.

`sns.setSMSAttributes(
   {
      attributes : {
                      DefaultSMSType : "Transactional"
                    }
    },
    function(error){
                  if(error){
                    console.log(error);
                   }
     }
 );`

Explanation- there are two types one is promotional which is default, and not time critical and one is transactional, time critical used for otp. There is a price difference I suppose in using either of the options. Upon reading your answer I tried the way you did and the sms were delayed, so I used the api given here to change to transactional and it gave instant messages.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SNS.html#publish-property

Comment: Is it a really working solution? I tried the method, but it says setSMSAttributes is not a function.

Comment: Last I checked it worked. Would check again today and confirm.

Comment: Thanks. Do you think I need to provide a specific version to AWS sdk to utilize the function?

Comment: This seems to work for me because it is coming up as transaction on my sns panel, but I having account limit issues at the moment. :(